# How to create summary from raw data

Tags: excel-formula

I am working in a excel file there I have raw data in a sheet actually it is expenses details of my office in different heads. I want to create a summary report based on that data. but the problem is, In raw data I have person name in column"A", expense head in column "B" & expense amount in column "C".
Now I need to create summary in other sheet in column "A" person name & in row 1 expense heads and in between the range of them spread the amount.
I know it is possible through pivot table But I was trying to do this by sumif formula.
Is it possible to do with formula without using pivot table. I am attaching an image for easy understanding of my problem.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIFS()` should be the solution to your problem. 
It works like follows.

- First parameter is your range you want to sum - In your case `RAW_DATA!$C$1:$C$21`
- Second parameter is the first criteria range - In your case `RAW_DATA!$A$1:$A$21`
- Third parameter is the criteria for the first criteria range - In your case `$A2`

`RAW_DATA!` is a reference to the sheet with the raw data.
`$A1` is a locked reference which means if you drag the formula only `1` will change whereas `A` is locked

`SUMIFS(RAW_DATA!$C$1:$C$21, RAW_DATA!$A$1:$A$21, $A2, RAW_DATA!$B$1:$B$21, B$2)`

If you input this in the first cell in your matrix and drag it should work.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks a Lot. :-)